# Qt cannot execute HTTP request in a class

Tags: c++, qt, c++17

I am trying to create a class that handles HTTP get requests; I have a REST service and I need to execute some gets to read JSON data. In other words, this class simply does an HTTP get and parses the JSON.

**.h**

```
#ifndef HTTPREQUEST_H
#define HTTPREQUEST_H

#include <QUrl>
#include <QObject>
#include <functional>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QDebug>

class HTTPRequest : public QObject {

    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QUrl url;
    QNetworkAccessManager* mAccessManager;
    std::function<void(const QString&)> action;

private slots:
    void replyFinished(QNetworkReply* reply);

public:
    explicit HTTPRequest(QObject *parent = nullptr, const QUrl& _url = {});
    void executeGet(const std::function<void(const QString&)>& onComplete);

};

#endif // HTTPREQUEST_H
```

**.cpp**

```
#include "httprequest.h"

HTTPRequest::HTTPRequest(QObject *parent, const QUrl& _url) : QObject(parent), url(_url) {
    mAccessManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(mAccessManager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &HTTPRequest::replyFinished);
}

void HTTPRequest::executeGet(const std::function<void(const QString&)>& onComplete) {
    QNetworkRequest request{QUrl{url}};
    mAccessManager->get(request);
    //qDebug() << "executeGet";

    action = onComplete;
    //qDebug() << "assign";
}

void HTTPRequest::replyFinished(QNetworkReply* reply) {
    //qDebug() << "onFinish";
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        action(QString{reply->readAll()});
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error(reply->errorString().toStdString());
    }
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

This class has only the `executeGet` method. It accepts a lambda because I want to execute it in different places and I want it to be used like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() {
    HTTPRequest req{this, QUrl{"http://www.website.com/1.json"}};
    req.executeGet([&](const QString& response){
        //work with response
    });
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked() {
    HTTPRequest req{this, QUrl{"http://www.website.com/2.json"}};
    req.executeGet([&](const QString& response){
        //work with response
    });
}
```

If you try to uncomment the `qDebug()` you'll see the messages *executeGet* and *assigned* but then you won't see *onFinish*. Why?

Am I doing something wrong with the lambda maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions where you create the `HTTPRequest` objects and execute them allocate the `req` on the stack as a local variable. Hence, as soon as these functions finish the `HTTPRequest` is deleted, even though the actual request is still happening in the background. You need to create the `HTTPRequest` objects on the heap and make sure they stay around until the actual request is complete and your on complete lambda is called:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() {
    auto *req = new HTTPRequest(this, QUrl(...));
    req->executeGet([req](const QString &response) {
        // Do other stuff...

        // Make sure we only delete `req` after the request finishes.
        delete req;
    });
}
```

Comment: Good catch! I didnt think about the fact that the lifetime of the thread spawned by QNetworkAccessManager could for sure exceed the lifetime of the local variable. Thank you!!

Comment: @PaulL Even if QNAM didn’t spawn a thread, it’d still be a problem – because the request class has to survive until the event loop spins and delivers completion notifications. Those will be lost as soon as the request is destroyed. Note that the `HTTPRequest` class is a bit of a misnomer, since it really processes the response. Requests are lightweight classes that aren’t even `QObject`s. The naming of this class is quite confusing given Qt conventions.

Comment: @KubaOber well, since I pass `this` as parameter I set the main window as the owner. That means that I do not have to take care of the lifetime of the object because Qt will. I simply have to remove `delete req;` and I should be ok